# Google Chrome "Redirect Loop" but not in other web browsers

Tags: php, html, mysql, google-chrome, session-variables

I implemented a website that hosts school files in a certain directory, the index page is simply a login page. When ever I visit this site using Google Chrome, it will constantly give me a "Redirect Loop Error", however, if I use any other browser then the site loads normally.

My site code for the index.php is below, any suggestions are appreciated.

the site url is: https://secure.fixnode.ca/

Thanks,
Phillip K

```
<?php
session_start();

function loggedin()
{
 if (isset($_SESSION['myusername']) || isset($_COOKIE['myusername']))
 {
    $loggedin = TRUE;
    return $loggedin;
 }
}

if (loggedin())
{
 header("Location: /login_success.php");
die();
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="user"; // Mysql username 
$password="password"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="database_name"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="table_name"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['username']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['password'];
$rememberme=$_POST['rememberme'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$encrypted_mypassword=md5($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$encrypted_mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
mysql_close();
// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) //user exists
{
  if ($rememberme=="on"){
      setcookie("myusername", $myusername, time()+7200);
   }
 elseif ($rememberme==""){
      $_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
   }

header("Location: /login_success.php");
exit();
}
else {
echo '<div class="alert">Incorrect Username or Password!</div>';
}
}
?>


<?php
// DETECT MOBILE DEVICE
//session_start();
$user_agent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$iphone = strpos($user_agent,"iPhone");
$android = strpos($user_agent,"Android");
$palmpre = strpos($user_agent,"webOS");
$berry = strpos($user_agent,"BlackBerry");
$ipod = strpos($user_agent,"iPod");

if($_GET['mobile_site'])
{
    if (strcmp($_GET['mobile_site'],"false")==0)
    $_SESSION['mobile_site']=false;
    if (strcmp($_GET['mobile_site'],"true")==0)
    $_SESSION['mobile_site']=true;
}
if ($iphone || $android || $palmpre || $ipod || $berry == true)
{
$_SESSION['mobile_device']=true;    //

if (isset($_SESSION['mobile_site']))
    {
    }
else
    $_SESSION['mobile_site']=true;
}
else
{
$_SESSION['mobile_site']=false;
$_SESSION['mobile_device']=false;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Secure Customer Login</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<script type="application/javascript" src="scripts/bubble_bookmark.js" charset="utf-></script>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/images/apple-touch-icon.png">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
<?php if($_SESSION['mobile_site']==true){ ?>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
<?php } ?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function navigator_Go(url) {
    window.location.assign(url); 
    }
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var addToHomeConfig = {
touchIcon: true,
};
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/structure.css">
<script>document.createElement('footer');</script>
</head>
<body>
<center><img src="/images/logo.png"></center>
<form class="box login" name="login" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
<fieldset class="boxBody">
  <label>Username</label>
  <input type="email" name="username" tabindex="1" placeholder="Email" required="required">
  <label><?php if($_SESSION['mobile_site']==true){ ?><a href="javascript:navigator_Go('recovery.php');" class="rLink" tabindex="5">Forget your password?</a><?php } ?><?php if($_SESSION['mobile_site']==false){ ?><a href="recovery.php" class="rLink" tabindex="5">Forget your password?</a><?php } ?>Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" tabindex="2" placeholder="Password" required="required">
</fieldset>
<footer>
  <label><input type="checkbox" tabindex="3" name="rememberme">Keep me logged in</label>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="btnLogin" tabindex="4">
</footer>
</form>
<footer id="main">
  &copy; 2011 Fixnode Computer Services.  All rights reserved.</a>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any URL on that subdomain sends the browser into a redirect loop. For example:

```
https://secure.fixnode.ca/loops-are-cool
```

It would appear there's something else doing the redirects. Perhaps in an .htaccess file?

Comment: I removed the .htaccess file in the secure. subdirectory, I only had a redirect script that redirected the user to https if he was on http. After removing the script (.htaccess file) I still continue to have redirect loop errors

Comment: Then it must be a configuration setting somewhere else (Apache config perhaps) that is causing the redirects. Why else would the URL i posted above redirect anywhere and not just return with a 404?

Comment: I investigated my apache directives and they are exactly the same as my other subdirectory https://storage.fixnode.ca/ (which works with chrome). After doing some more investigation I realized that if I change my subdirectory to something else other then secure.fixnode.ca (like login.fixnode.ca) then it works with google chrome. SO it seems there is an error in google chrome that doesn't like using secure. for a subdirectory

Comment: I assure you it has nothing to do with the name of the subdomain (secure) in Chrome. I get the same redirect loop in for example Firefox (on OSX).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have a redirect rule somewhere that redirect all incoming requests to your index.php.

Comment: It was my .htaccess file. Google Chrome does not like RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off instead you need to do RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$

Answer (score 0):

make your function loggedin() `return true;` when logged in and `return false`;
when not logged in and check the function with `if(loggedin() == true)`
and instead of `die()` use `exit;`

Comment: I did everything you suggested and still have the redirect error in google chrome.